# Visual Studio not catching XAML Static Resource error in Debug mode that cause crash in Release

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xaml, maui

I have a .NET MAUI application that launches to a page that contains the following control:

```
<Switch
                        x:Name="swRemainLoggedIn"
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        IsToggled="{Binding RemainLoggedIn}"
                        Style="{StaticResource StandardSwitch}" />
```

The `StandardSwitch` resource does not exist as a static resource in the project, so this code should throw some kind of error. However, the app builds fine in Debug mode and only crashes on launch in Release mode.

The output I've looked at for release mode doesn't provide any useful feedback. I only figured out that the Style property was the problem through trial and error. Anybody know why Visual Studio might be missing this error?

Have tried to figure out how to turn on verbose logging for Release mode, but even that hasn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

We usually use the following methods to deal with XAML code:

**1.xamlc**

.NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) XAML is compiled directly into intermediate language (IL) with the XAML compiler (XAMLC). XAML compilation offers a number of benefits:

> - It performs compile-time checking of XAML, notifying you of any    errors.
> - It removes some of the load and instantiation time for XAML elements.
> - It helps to reduce the file size of the final assembly by no longer    including .xaml files.

XAML compilation is enabled by default in .NET MAUI apps, removing any `XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Skip)` statements will ensure that XAML compilation is enabled.

Alternatively, XAML compilation can be forcibly enabled by passing `XamlCompilationOptions.Compile` to the [XamlCompilationAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.xaml.xamlcompilationattribute?view=net-maui-7.0):

```
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
```

In this example, XAML compilation is enabled for all of the XAML contained within the assembly, with XAML errors being reported at compile-time rather than runtime.

XAML compilation can also be enabled at the type level:

```
[XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    ...
}
```

For more information, check document: [XAML compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/xamlc).

**2.XAML Hot Reload for .NET MAUI**

.NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) XAML Hot Reload is a Visual Studio feature that enables you to view the result of XAML changes in your running app, without having to rebuild your project. Without XAML Hot Reload, you have to build and deploy your app every time you want to view the result of a XAML change.

XAML Hot Reload is enabled by default in Visual Studio 2022. If it's been previously disabled, it can be enabled by selecting Debug > Options > XAML Hot Reload from the Visual Studio menu bar.

For more information, check document: [XAML Hot Reload for .NET MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/hot-reload?tabs=vswin).

Comment: I tried adding the 
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)] line of code before the namespace line in my app.xaml.cs and still Visual Studio 2022 is not detecting missing static resources.  Any other ideas??